# How can I select document with conditional subdocs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to find documents with Mongoose that contains at least one subdocument, respecting the $elemMatch condition.

My main doc sample is like this:

```
{
    desc: 'Sample',
    user: 10,
    prices: [{ code: 1, price: 10 }, { code: 2, price: 0 }]
}
```

I need the documents that contains at least one subdoc with price bigger than 0. If doc no have price bigger than 0, the main doc may be discarded.

With $elemMatch, I can filter the subdocs, but not the main doc:

```
Prod.find({ user: 10}, { prices: { $elemMatch: { price: { $gt: 0 } } } })
```

With this, I have the document:

```
[{
    desc: 'Sample',
    user: 10,
    prices: []
}]
```

When should it be:

```
[]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can add the condition in the query operator. Something like this `Prod.find({ user: 10, "prices.price": { $gt: 0 } }, { prices: { $elemMatch: { price: { $gt: 0 } } } })`

Comment: Yes, it's a solution. But I have one more condition, with code. I will update the question. Thanks!